# pandas - idiomatic way to stash rows filtered out of dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

What is the idiomatic way to split a dataframe into two by a condition?  Or put another way, to filter a dataframe by a condition but keep the filtered out rows in a new dataframe?

I was thinking I could filter the original dataframe for the inverse of the 'filtered out by condition' rows using the tilde , like this:

```
# this obviously doesnt work, though it would seem idiomatic to me. 
# is there a clean / idiomatic solution?
vowels = df[~nonvowels]
```

```
import pandas as pd

dl = [
    {'letter':'a','number':1,'vowel':True}, 
    {'letter':'b','number':2,'vowel':False}, 
    {'letter':'c','number':3,'vowel':False},
    {'letter':'d','number':4,'vowel':False},
    {'letter':'e','number':5,'vowel':True},
    {'letter':'f','number':6,'vowel':False},
    {'letter':'g','number':7,'vowel':False},
    {'letter':'x','number':24,'vowel':False},
    {'letter':'y','number':25,'vowel':None},
    {'letter':'z','number':26,'vowel':False}
    ]

df = pd.DataFrame(dl)

print (df)

# a filter
nonvowels = df[df['vowel'] == False]

# one solution- i know i can do this with the drop method, passing it the 'filtered df''s index to the original df drop method as a list...
vowels = df.drop(nonvowels.index.tolist())

# but i was curious if there was an idiomatic way to store filtered rows of a 
# dataframe and also store/keep it's 'inverse' 
# as stated above, my inuition thinks once i have nonvowels in a df, i should be able to do something like:
# vowels = df[~nonvowels]
# but that doesnt work...

print (nonvowels)
print (vowels)
```

Comment: You can just reverse the condition. `vowels = df[df.vowel == True]`

Comment: For bracket & tilde to work, the condition inside the brackets needs to be a series of Booleans that has the same length as your dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`df.loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) + [`df.index.difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.difference.html) with `nonvowels.index` to achieve what you're looking for (and yes, this is idiomatic):

```
vowels = df.loc[df.index.difference(nonvowels.index)]
```

Output:

```
>>> vowels
  letter  number vowel
0      a       1  True
4      e       5  True
8      y      25  None
```

Comment: this index-based-"difference" approach is what in the back of my mind i thought could make sense- though i guess i assumed there might be a more succinct method to do it ;). thank you

Comment: You don't consider this succinct? :P

Answer (score 2):

The conditioner, or the *filterer*, is `df['vowel'] == False`; not `df[df['vowel'] == False]`. So instead of negating the already-filtered dataframe, you may negate the conditioner and use it. But before that let's change it to `df['vowel'] == True` since you have some `None`s which perhaps means `False`. So

```
cond = df['vowel'] == True

vowels = df[cond]
non_vowels = df[~cond]
```

Comment: thanks, i didn't realize i could define a cond that way and then reuse it.

Comment: By the way, if you plan to do further manipulations on the newly-generated frames, please consider putting `.copy()` to their end, e.g., `vowels = df[cond].copy()` so as to avoid the infamous *SettingWithCopyWarning*.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boolean series to split the data frame into different segments. The different segments in this example, vowels, non-vowels and null values can be split by:

```
is_vowel_boolean_series = df["vowel"] == True

vowels_df = df[is_vowel_boolean_series]

nonvowels_df = df[~is_vowel_boolean_series]

nulls_df = df[df["vowel"].isna()]
```